# Where to find Joomla components for 1.0.X?

Tags: joomla

I need to add new functionality to an old Joomla 1.0.15 installation. To be concrete, I need to add a component that allows me to add custom javascript to my content.

I know that there is the option to edit the html source of the content but I rather would like to use a module for this.

So I see two options (correct me if there are more):

1. Update Joomla to at least version 1.5 (From some forum posts I found out that can be somewhat complicated). I don't know if it is worth the effort since new functionality requirements come rarely (and I think my client doesn't want to pay for a Joomla version update).
2. Find an appropriate component and leave the old installation as it is.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Just out of interest why are you running an old version of Joomla? I'm sure there has probably been some security fixes along the way since the version you have and it always makes sense to keep installations up to date to prevent any vulnerabilities

Comment: @Vince It is a new client for me. The originial installation was done by a different company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla 1.0 extensions are not provided on the Joomla Extensions Directory anymore therefore getting hold of them will be very hard. There are probably still a handful of websites out there that haven't yet deleted their 1.0 extensions, that might still be available.

You should really be using Joomla 2.5 or 3.x though

Answer (score 0):

As Lodder points out, Joomla 1.0 extensions are no longer listed in the Joomla Extensions Directory but you can still search JED for suitable extensions and check the developers websites for a Joomla 1.0 version.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/head-code

Of course, a Google search might work too.